# Is there an easy way to use all digit buttons with the left hand?

Tags: starcraft-2, keyboard

**Intro**
I play RTSs (Starcraft 2, specifically) and now realize that I want to use more than the <kbd>1</kbd> - <kbd>5</kbd> digits to bind my army / buildings / etc.

**Problem**
I cannot precisely hit the <kbd>7</kbd> - <kbd>0</kbd> (neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> - <kbd>0</kbd> nor <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> - <kbd>0</kbd>) keys without looking on the keyboard (my right hand controls the mouse, of course).

**Question**
Do you know an easy way to hit <kbd>7</kbd>,<kbd>8</kbd>,<kbd>9</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd> with the left hand?
Is there some mark that my hand could use (e.g. the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) or something else?

I don't want to buy any additional device. My question is all about behavior, not environment. Plus, you probably know that pro-gamers use a normal keyboard and are totally fine with it.

For example, right now I realize that if I rotate the keyboard clockwise a little, access to <kbd>7</kbd> - <kbd>0</kbd> becomes easier.

Comment: [Grow bigger hands.](http://www.eastsideboxing.com/forum/showthread.php?t=44091)

Comment: Hey Meta, jokes are acceptable comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have 6 and 7 remapped to F2 and F3 for my production buildings and main bases. If you have all your production on F2 you can just tab through them to select the different types.

Also, if you're Protoss you can just hit W to select all warp gates.

Comment: Great idea. I've already mapped `~` to `0`. I used to have `F2..F4` for camera but now I realize that I can use a bit awkward `Alt+1` to recall and something like `shift+F5` to bind camera. So... I can bind `0` to `~`, `7..9` to `F2..F4` and I'm done!
For now it's a best answer. Thank you!

Comment: I've tried and it works!

Answer (score 6):

I use this mouse:
[image: Razer Naga]

Maybe a [Naga](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRFQN.jpg) would be good for you (or mouse with a similar button layout). It would definitely allow you to get to all your hot keys easier (I've used it in SC2 for just such a reason).

Comment: Obviously, this isn't strictly for left handed number access, but I figured I'd post another option.

Comment: good idea I thought about it. But this way my right hand will execute more actions that left do. I give a + for this answer and will change OP

Answer (score 3):

How about a standalone numpad that you can place on the left side of your keyboard?  That way you'd be easily able to hold shift or ctrl while uniquely identifying which number you were pressing.  Something as simple as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0019W7HKE) seems like it would do pretty well and is cheap.  For a more expensive option, you could get something like the [Microsoft Sidewinder X6](http://www.engadget.com/2008/08/20/microsoft-intros-sidewinder-x6-keyboard-and-x5-mouse/) that has a numpad that is able to be locked into either side of the keyboard.

Comment: I think that with external numpad I'll have same troubles - I will not be able to precisely and fast click on device that lies near a keyboard. Please see _edit_ section in OP

Comment: Upvoted, but of course a cheaper alternative is to switch to mousing with your left hand, and operating the keyboard with your right. A lot of "pro" gamers do this, despite being naturally right-handed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm used to my hand straying quite a bit from the homerow and general 1-handed typing (no, not for **that**) and what I do is just hit Ctrl/Shift with my thumb and the actual number with my pinky.

Comment: actually I believe that pro-gamers use this. But I found an answer more 'natural' for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of keyboard do you have?  If you can get used to an ergonomic keyboard, you might find it easier because the keyboard is split.  Mine has the number keys like this:

```
123456  7890
```

Comment: I've tried with microsoft ergo 4000:  
left hand makes a bit longer way to right side of keyboard and precision still low...

Answer (score -1):

Move the keyboard about 50cm to the left and use the numpad.